# Send and Receive Binary SMS in Android?

Tags: android, binary-data

I am working on an POC in which my task is to send the DATA SMS or Binary SMS. and Receive the  Binary SMS.
I am working with the below code but Its failed to send SMS

```
sms.sendDataMessage(dest, src, port, message.getBytes(), sentPI, deliveredPI);
```

Please let me know the mistake in my code. And Suggest me in this task.

Comment: whats the error? post your logcat here?

Comment: I am not getting any error in the LogCat....Also I have passed the port as 8888. Is it correct?